# Objective-C to Swift Pointers : Which is better?

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, memory

I'm using some Objective-C APIs in my Swift project, and most of them require pointers. I have managed to bridge them and get them working, but I found 2 ways to do it, and would like to know any insight to what method would be better for the app's memory management? 
Take for example this method definition in Objective-C:

```
MyObjectiveCApiMethod(MyObjectiveCStructA * myStructPtr)
```

The approaches in Swift I have found to work with this method are:

A:

```
let myStructPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<MyObjectiveCApiStructA>.allocate(capacity: 1)
var myStruct: MyObjectiveCApiStructA = MyObjectiveCApiStructA()
memset(&myStruct, 0x00, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myStruct))
myStructPtr.initialize(to: myStruct)   
MyObjectiveCApiMethod(myStructPtr)
```

or a much simpler B:

```
var myStruct: MyObjectiveCApiStructA = MyObjectiveCApiStructA()
MyObjectiveCApiMethod(&myStruct)
```

What do you think? 
Thanks!

Comment: I would say to always choose the one that looks more swift - B, because the compiler can probably optimise that and it is more readable.

Comment: Without seeing any context for what your types and functions are, option B looks fine.